# vshost-clr2.exe has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm working on an app in VS 2010 on wind2008.  It's a .Net 3.5 app that use .Net 2.0 library.

I change all Frameworks to 3.5 .Net and uncheck "Enable the visual studio hosting process"

But When I debug my solution I got this error :

```
    Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: AnalyseFarm.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5326f157
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bdfe0
  Exception Code:   c000041d
  Exception Offset: 000000000000aa7d
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1036
  Additional Information 1: 5ecb
  Additional Information 2: 5ecbd308407466ba89616cb69c9e62d8
  Additional Information 3: 9ac0
  Additional Information 4: 9ac06af1219db569f0ee193c24745b31
```

any idea , beast regards

Comment: my idea would be to submit this to microsoft help. If you can't debug any application, then that is a serious issue that should be looked at.  This isn't really material for SO

Comment: actualy ,This error came just for this application , the others works just fine .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Exception Code:   c000041d

This tells the tale, that's STATUS_FATAL_USER_CALLBACK_EXCEPTION, "An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback".  Your program threw an exception and it wasn't handled.  Which normally automatically breaks into the debugger and displays the Exception Assistant.

However, the exception occurred at a *very* awkward time, just when the operating system was in a state where it cannot afford to go through the normal rigamarole that it goes through when a thread dies with an exception.  This kind of mishap usually occurs when the callback was triggered by 32-bit code but the exception occurred in 64-bit code, there's no good mechanism to marshal 64-bit exceptions back into 32-bit code, the exception information cannot be properly interpreted by such code since it includes 64-bit pointer values.  Or the other way around.  Windows messages generated by the window manager tend to fall in this category.  Beware that this is just a rough guess at the reason, you need to find the real one.

You do so by forcing the debugger to stop at the code where the exception is thrown, *before* the operating system is asked to deal with it.  Use the Debug + Exceptions dialog, tick the Thrown checkboxes to force the debugger to stop at the throw location.

Comment: thank Hans , the Debug + Exceptions dialog, tick the Thrown checkboxes to force the debugger to stop at the throw location. this is the solution